# Overlap two png images with javascript and save new image as file

Tags: javascript, png, overlapping

In a javascript script I need to superimpose two png images into one and then save the new image as a single file. **My script does not work inside a webpage but completely batch.**

The function that I imagined was something like this:

*newPng = mergePng(png1, png2);*

I have long searched for a javascript library that would allow me to get the result I wanted, but I did not find it. I've also tried among the previous questions here on Stackoverflow, but I have not found any solutions.

Does anyone know if the function I'm looking for exists?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) first show us what you tried.
2) try with canvas

Comment: Hi Andrei. Canvas is, as far as I know, an HTML element. The png images I want to overlay are not within a webpage.

Comment: I guess you are using node.... if so... try this https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Answer (score 1):

You can draw png files inside a canvas like this:

```
drawing = new Image();
drawing2 = new Image();
drawing2.src = "draw2.png";
drawing.src = "draw.png";
drawing.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(drawing,0,0);
   context.drawImage(drawing2,0,0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, moigonz. My javascript, however, is NOT executed within a web page but only in batch. Canvas, if I'm not mistaken, is an element of HTML.

Comment: `drawing.src = "C:\users\s\videos\draw.png";` returns error. What should I do @moigonz I'm typing that in console.